# iAd and didFailToReceiveAdWithError

Tags: iphone, iad

I'm getting a "didFailToReceiveAdWithError" message in the console while running in the simulator. Is this the same method as the "didFailToReceiveAdWithError" method referred to in the message?

My view controller implements ADBannerViewDelegate protocol, and in particular the -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error method. The Ad's delegate is set to the view controller.

I haven't found any other methods resembling a "didFailToReceiveAdWithError" in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. That message in the console is indeed corresponding to the iAd's delegate function. It is normal to get this as the test iAd fill rate is not 100%. When there are no ad to serve, this delegate (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error will be called by iOS.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. In that case it looks like there's no problem with my iAd setup and I'm good to go.